# Run command to open network connections list box

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, cmd.exe, run-dialog

Is there any way I can open the network connection list box (see image) using Run or cmd?

Im currently on Windows 10.
[image: Screenshot of network connections list box on Windows 10]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open the network connections list from command line you can use:

- `explorer ms-availablenetworks:`

> Press Win key+ R key to open Run dialog, type the following sentences:
>
> - `ms-settings:network-wifi`(Available Wi-Fi)
> - `ms-settings:network-wifisettings`(Manage Wi-Fi Settings )
>
> [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app)
>
> <sub>[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/908616fe-cb97-4e4e-a17a-a15e81a8de53/is-there-a-mssettingsnetworkwifi-call-that-will-open-the-view-available-networks-screen?forum=win10itprogeneral)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [How to Create a Show Available Networks shortcut in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/81130-create-available-networks-shortcut-windows-10-a.html)
- [Open “Show available networks” panel from command line or windows message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923490/open-show-available-networks-panel-from-command-line-or-windows-message)